# Eclipse (Indigo) subversive 0.7.9: bad_record_mac

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssl, eclipse-plugin, subversive

When trying to use subversive with my beanstalk svn repo (https://beanstalkapp.com) I get the following type of error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
```

This works fine via the command line, just not with eclipse or the subversive svn plugin. I've read that its to do with not allowing old versions of SSL but cannot find any way of fixing it in eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: can you connect and work with the repository using the problematic subsersive/eclipse environment without ssl... http://beanstalkapp.com?

Comment: Assuming no sensitive info in repo, switch to non-ssl will remove many factors to troubleshoot.  The repo must allow non-SLL connections. 1. cd to eclipse workspace and to project w/svn issue. Run: `svn info` record URL shown like `https://somebeanstockthing.com/blah/` Make copy of this url, but change the https:// to  http://.  Switch your working copy with: `svn switch --relocate <oldurl> <newurl>` like this: `svn switch --relocate https://somebeanstockthing.com/blah/ http://somebeanstockthing.com/blah/` if no deeper SVN problem pop up,svn info should confirm url change, restart ide

Comment: once you do this, still have problem in eclipse?  If so, same error?

Comment: Changing the URL works! Thanks very much Ray!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems my repository is requiring me to redirect to the https url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, this seems to be an issue with SVNKit 1.3.6 (and the 1.7 betas) and JDK6. I was also having the same issue using my beanstalk svn repo. I think the bug may be related to this report.

http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-176

Once you look more into it it's apparently a longstanding problem in JDK6 and that type of forced SSL connection from the server, though their solution did not work for me whatsoever (maybe I was totally doing it wrong).

So the "solutions" as it were, are to:
a. Develop with JDK7
b. Just start Eclipse with a 7.0 JVM (-vm parameter, continue developing with JDK6)
c. Go back to SVNKit 1.3.5 (again continue using JDK6)
d. Forget SVNKit altogether and use JavaHL (omg this is a whole new can of worms if you are using 64bit JVM)
e. Try adding that setting in eclipse.ini (I tried for hours... still got the same error trying to use svn repo)

I unfortunately went with option D for now. The rest I tested and all worked as well (cept the last).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use beanstalk without SSL (thanks Ray) which solves the problem for me.

Comment: I made that comment before using Stack overflow... should have made it an Answer :), but I appreciate it @Nick

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3